# DataVirtualization using IObservableVector<T> in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, data-virtualization

I load large set of data into the ItemsControl [ 100000 items] in my Windows 8.1 application. When I could read the MSDN documentation, I could see that IObservableVector is the best choice to implement the Random DataVirtualization concept.

Unfortunately I am not able to find the good sample to replicate the IObservableVector implementation in Windows 8.1 with the DataVirtualization concept. 
Could you please anyone suggest me to get the exact sample which uses the IObservableVector implementation ?

Comment: Having similar issues...IObservableVector has problems...I don't see updated docs or recommendations from MS on this at this time

Answer (score 0):

Please, check my asnwer to similar question [Random access data virtualization for ListView on Windows Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361856/random-access-data-virtualization-for-listview-on-windows-runtime/28491953#28491953)

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to solve this with Rx. Please see
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/995043/An-experiment-with-random-access-data-virtualisati